# Xarray interpolate returns nan for all values

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm trying to extract the value of a variable (rainrate) for a given point from a NetCDF dataset. The shape of the NetCDF dataset is `24 (time) x 720 (outlat) x 1680 (outlon).` The data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/373j0i9xth621jc/ST4.20170823.newregridded.nc?dl=0).

**What I have tried:**

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.open_dataset(path_to_NetCDF.nc)
data_ts = ds.interp(outlat=[35.5], outlon=[-97.33], method='nearest') #or method ='linear'
data_rain_rate = data_ts['rainrate'][:, 0, 0].to_series()
df_rain_rate = pd.DataFrame(data_rain_rate).reset_index()
```

All the values returned are nan even though the entire data is not nan. What am I doing wrong, and how can I understand why the code is outputting just nan?

**Desired output:** A time series of the variable (rainrate).

[image: A screenshot of the data showing values]
A screenshot of the data showing values

Comment: Looks like you need to fix your data. Longitude and latitude are stored as variables, not coordinates. outlat and outlon are not actually longitude and latitude, given outlat has a maximum value of 719. You'll need to change outlat and outlon to the actually lon/lats

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you.

I made the following change: `ds = ds.rename({'latitude': 'outlat', 'longitude': 'outlon'}).set_coords(['outlon', 'outlat'])`